# How do I use the @ sign in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, variables

A user on SO recently gave me this Query to put into MYSQL, but I don't know what to do with the @ sign.

```
SELECT  user_id, GLength(LineString(utm, @mypoint))
FROM    users
WHERE   MBRWithin(utm, LineString(Point(X(@mypoint) - 20, Y(@mypoint - 20)), Point(X(@mypoint) + 20, Y(@mypoint + 20))
        AND GLength(LineString(utm, @mypoint)) <= 20
```

I'm doing everything in console. How would I assign @mypoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) here. They're pretty sweet.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable.  This is a legal SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @mypoint Int = 1;
```

You can put it before that query and it will insert 1 into every @mypoint.  I am not sure what datatype your @mypoint should be, but that's the idea.